# The 'imagem_post' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to get the images to appear on the screen. I'm trying to solve this it seems my code is not recognizing the information from my model.py or view.py , this all happens when I try to call the information in the html tag. Help me understand where I'm going wrong please.

```
model.py

import django
from django.db import models
from categorias.models import Categoria
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone



class Post(models.Model):
titulo_post = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Titulo')
autor_post = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
verbose_name='Autor')
data_post = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, 
verbose_name='Data')
conteudo_post = models.TextField(verbose_name='Conteúdo')
excerto_post = models.TextField(verbose_name='Excerto')
categoria_post = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, 
blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Categoria')
imagem_post = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_img/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True, 
verbose_name='Imagem')
publicado_post = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Publicado')

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo_post
```

In the img tag is where I'm trying to reference my images when I put: image_post.url then it starts to give an error if I don't put .url the error disappears but I run out of images on the screen

```
 index.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block conteudo %}
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div class="card-columns mt-4">
            <!-- FOR LOOP -->

            {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="card">

                <a href="post.html">
                    <img class="card-img-top" 
                    src="{{ post.imagem_post.url }}" 
                    alt="{{ post.titulo_post.url }}">
                </a>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <a href="post.html">A wonderful </a>
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">When, while the lovgleams steal ...</p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <small class="text-muted">hoje | 1 comentário | 
                         Tecnologia</small>
                    </p>

                    <div class="text-right">
                        <a href="post.html" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Ler 
                             `enter code here`mais...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <!--/FOR LOOP-->

        </div>
        <!--/CONTENT-->
        <!-- _pagination.html -->
{% include 'parciais/_pagination.html'%}
        <!-- _pagination.html -->
{% endblock %}
```

This is the views.py file

```
views.py 


from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from .models import Post


class PostIndex(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'posts/index.html'
paginate_by = 3
context_object_name = 'posts'

class PostBusca(PostIndex):
pass

class PostCategoria(PostIndex):
pass

class PostDetalhes(UpdateView):
pass
```

Comment: Please post only in English - this is actually Stack policy. Even tho I dont understand a word here is your problem: you have blank=True, null=True set so you probably created a post  image instance without a real image file associated so it cannot have a url attached

Comment: what do i need to do for the images to appear?

Comment: upload them correctly. Just set the blank=False, null=False and you will see where the problem is

Comment: Somehow this helped: (1) set blank = False, null = False (2) Make an IF:
{% if object.post_image %}
    YOUR CODE (in my case, post.html)
{%endif %} (3) make: python manage.py makemigrations (4) Make: python manage.py migrate

Comment: I will post this as an aswer so others can learn from it as well

Comment: If it helped you, please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

This error is caused by having a `ImageField` or `FileField` with `null=True`. When creating a model instance (Here a `Post`) without actually uploading the file, the field itself is created and filled with `null` in db. So when you call `your_instance.image_field.url` before checking if its not empty you will end up with aforementioned error as there can't be any file to create url for.

### **How to avoid this**

whenever you call `your_instance.image_field.url` first check if it is not `None` (null in db). so

```
# longer version for readability 
if your_instance.image_field is not None:

    return your_instance.image_field.url
else:
    return None
```

or in template ``` {% if your_instance.image_field %}{{ your_instance.image_field.url }}{% endif %}

### Better solution (imo)

on your every model containing the `ImageField` or `FileField` create a method returning file's url or None

example

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

    ...
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    
    def get_image_url(self):
        if self.image:
            return self.image.url
        
        return None
```

this way your will not have to worry about `if` statements every time you want to call the url